# figure out the MSDate 2 years in the past

Tags: c#

I have a MSDate something like 41512
I want to find out 2 years in the past from that date. 
Right now I am in C# and the 41512 date is a string.

Comment: Convert to `int` and subtract `2*365`? Depends on your definition of a *year*...

Comment: What have your tried? What is an "MSDate"? What does the number 41512 represent? It seems that it's a count of days since 1 Jan 1900, since 28 August is 41,512 days since 1 Jan 1900. A clear problem statement and code samples showing your work so far helps us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The msDate is the number of days since 1900-01-00, so you can calculate it by taking `new DateTime(1900,01,01)` and adding the msDate, then taking 2 (1 to account for 00-00 instead of 00-01, and 1 because you don't count the target day itself).   Easier still, the FromOADate function takes care of this for you.
You can then subtract two years to get the new date.
You can optionally convert this date back to an integer using the ToOADate function.

```
int msDate = 41512;
//DateTime d = (new DateTime(1900, 01, 01)).AddDays(msDate - 2).AddYears(-2);
DateTime d = DateTime.FromOADate(msDate).AddYears(-2);
msDate = int.Parse(d.ToOADate().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your "MSDate" a count of days since a particular epoch (an epoch is the zero point on a calendar)? If so, you can do something like this:

```
public DateTime MsDateToDateTime( string msDate )
{
  int daysSinceEpoch ;
  bool parsed = int.TryParse( msDate , out daySinceEpoch ) ;
  if ( !parsed ) throw new ArgumentException("msDate") ;

  Datetime value = epoch.AddDays( daysSinceEpoch ) ;
  return value ;
}

// our epoch is 1 January 1900 00:00:00
private static readonly DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1900,1,1) ;
```

Once it's a `DateTime`, you can manipulate it however you like. You might read up on the `DateTime.AddYears()` method.

Going the other way:

```
public string DateTimeToMsDate( DateTime dt )
{
   return ((int) (dt-epoch).TotalDays ).ToString() ;
}
```